# mySQL: one entry multiple strings vs multiple entries

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

At the minute im working on a complex database. I've got one table where I'd like to insert Data every day from dozents of Users.

Example:
There are 200 recipes for menus (each column a recipe) and 200+ Users. Every User is using a recipe between 1 and 3 times a day. in Addition to that i want to track the ingredients and the amount of the ingredients. Even more Data to it, like an evaulation of how difficult cooking was, how nice it tasted and so on.

First idea was to make one entry per usage:
[user id, timestamp, recipe#1, recipe#2, ... , recipe#200] // daily up to 3 entries per user

Details of the recipe would be in an array. I was wondering if I could make that easier. I want to synchronise the User's app and the database once per week. So could it be easier to make one entry for the week and differenciate the recipe usuage with a timestamp in that array?

Second idea:
[user id, recipe#1,...,recipe#200]
=>`'1','"details","timestamp"','"details","timestamp"','"details","timestamp"'` 
// weekly one entry per user

If I want to show charts with stats about the recipes Idea1 would be easy, but depending on the users and the entries of those my database grow almost exponential. Could it be better to go with idea2 to reduce it for one entry per week and differenciate with timestamps inside those arrays?

I also dont like the idea of maintaining a structure like this. Adding more recipes wouldnt be very dynamic. Basicly Users are growing, recipes are growing, details a dynamic, time is stamps are getting inserted without an end..

At the end of the day I want to display stats, behaviour depending on user, on time, be able to be sorted by every category possible - which gives me a headache :D

Answer (score 0):

Always go with multiple entries if you need to run queries on it for comparing and calculating.

Could you please share your whole database structure? I would go with more related tables. Preferable not add arrays into the database, see the database more like an array already to collect data in a better way.

I would go with something like cooking_id, user_id, recipe_id, difficulty, taste, timestamp, and create a new post for each time. Then in recipe table you have something like: recipe_id, name, details (maybe ingredients). Depends how you wanna measure things.

If you need to measure ingredients, you could make ingredients a separate table and create a related table for the recipe. Like for ingredients: ingredients_id, name. And for the related table: ingredients_id, recipe_id, grams. (here you can make ingredients_id and recipe_id together as a primary key.

It was some time since I last worked or study more deeply in database structure, hope I could give you some advice at least :)